# What do I have to be aware of when installing Reporting Services on a productive SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a running sql server installation on which I would like to install the reporting services module. Now because it is very important that the sql server it self keeps available and running without any interruptions I get a little scary about this step.

Now my question. Are there any pittfalls I have to be aware of before I install the module? E.g. does the server restart during the installation?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this change in a virtual machine first?

For example, use the Disk2vhd application (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx) to make a snapshot of your current production system. Then, use the VHD that was created in Microsoft Virtual PC, Hyper-V, or Windows 7 native VHD boot.

If you try a virtual machine for testing, disable networking or create a private network before starting the virtual machine! Having two servers with the same name and SID on your network is a Bad Thing.

(If you're not using virtual machines, isn't it time? :)